# MYSQL How to set if statement with variables which the variables value in "where"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question for complex mysql script , below

```
select * from table where 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP() >  @var (if(schedule_time > created_time),#true @var=schedule_time + 900, # fales @var= created_time + 900).
```

anyone can help?

Thanks!

Wilson

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do? Show some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: What are `#true` and `#false` in the middle of an `IF` function?

Comment: it is the calendar system dataset, have scheduled DateTime and record created time, because the user will create the record at 9:10 am, but the record schedule datetime at 9:00 am. now i would like to search the record if the schedule DateTime /created record time over 15 mins.

Comment: #true  = if the statement is true,# fales = if the statement is false

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a variable, just use an expression that returns the time you want to compare with.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() > GREATEST(schedule_time, created_time) + 900
```